# modify a phone number cleanup regex to handle a leading 1 digit

Tags: regex

I have a regex that already takes care of standardizing formatting of U.S. phone numbers, however it doesn't deal with a leading 1.

```
var cleanTelephoneNumber = function(tel) {
  var regexObj = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
  if (regexObj.test(tel)) {
    return tel.replace(regexObj, "($1) $2-$3");
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
```

how can I get it to strip out a leading one if it exists and still continue to parse correctly

e.g.

- +1-555-235-2444
- 1-555-235-2444
- 1.555.235-2444
- 1 555 235 2444
- 555-235-2444

should all translate to 
(555) 235-2444

I'd like to just modify the regex I already have

`/^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/`

Comment: start by counting the number of digits, if it's more than 10 you know you have a leading `1` or `+1` that should be stripped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your regex to use this:

```
^(?:\+?1?[-.\s]?)(\d{3})([-.\s])(\d{3})\2(\d{4})$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/kO3bG1/2)**

[image]

The idea of the regex is:

```
^(?:\+?1?[-.\s]?) can have +1 and a separator
 (\d{3})          must contain 3 digits
 ([-.\s])         store a separator
 (\d{3})          follow by 3 digits
 \2               use the same separator
 (\d{4})$         follow by 4 digits
```